# How do I reference a file path containing spaces in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, variables, space, quotes

All I want to do is read in a list of directories from a file and list the files in the directories.   The problem is that the directory paths have spaces in them, so this doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Spec;

open DIRNAMES, "<./dirnames";
while(my $dirname=<DIRNAMES>) {
    opendir DIR,$dirname or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    # Use a regular expression to ignore files beginning with a period
        next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
        print "$file\n";
    }
    closedir(DIR);
}
exit 0;
```

Nothing seems to work in line 6; $dirname doesn't work, neother does "$dirname", nor $"dirname"

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to remove the newline ending at the end of the line you placed in `$dirname`. Just add

```
chomp($dirname);
```